# How to pass parameter to @RequestParam from Spring form?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-form

Got a Spring MVC app, two Entities - Player and PlayerDetails, would like to add PlayerDetails to existing Player, but to do so I need to have a player id passed through parameter. 
But I can't pass a paremeter from JSP page, where I'm using Spring form. Still getting **"Required String parameter 'playerId' is not present"**.
I got the value already on JSP page, but the issue is to pass it through form to method.
When I remove @RequestParam from method, and hardcode "theInt2" inside method everything is ok.

PlayerDetailsController.class

```
  @PostMapping("/savePlayerDetails")
    public String savePlayerDetails(@RequestParam("playerId") String theInt,
                    @ModelAttribute("details") PlayerDetails playerDetails){

     int theInt2 = Integer.parseInt(theInt);

     playerDetailsService.savePlayerDetails(theInt2, playerDetails);

     return "redirect:/players/list";
    }
```

details-form.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<form:form action="savePlayerDetails" modelAttribute="details" method="POST">

    <form:hidden path="id"/>
    Date of birth: <form:input path="dateOfBirth"/>
    Email: <form:input path="email"/>
    Preferred Foot: <form:input path="preferredFoot"/>
    Short info: <form:input path="shortInfo"/>
    <br><br>
    ${player.playerId}  <!-- just for test, player id is shown here -->

<input type="submit" value="Save" class="save" />
</form:form>
```

Comment: Printing something to the screen is not the same as making it part of the form.

Comment: Know that, was only printing it to check if I got it passed to that JSP page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not passing `playerId` from your form, add another input to you form like below

```
<input type="hidden" name="playerId" value="${player.playerId}"/>
```

or

```
<form:hidden path="playerId"/>
```

should also work

Comment: Solved with that solution. Thanks!